# Rails rake db:setup fails on server: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running rake db:setup on my server, and I am getting:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'
```

(I added RAILS_ENV=production)

This is on a ubuntu, nginx, passenger, mysql setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either MySQL isn't running, or it's not configured to put the sock-file in the right place. Run something like `ps aux | grep mysql` to check if it's running. If it's running and the error persists, check if the file `/tmp/mysql.sock` exists. You can configure it in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

On my ubuntu machine its configured to `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. Either change your mysql settings, or change `config/database.yml` in your Rails app.

Comment: It is running for sure, as I have a wordpress blog on the same server, let me try what you said out.

Comment: mysqld.sock, what is that a file? mine is completely empty.

Comment: /tmp/mysql.sock doesnt' exist...do I just create that emtpy file like: touch mysql.sock ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and after trying everything I discovered that this occurs if you install mysql after you have installed rails.

Reinstalling rails solved the issue for me.

Of course this advice is only relevant if iain's answer doesn't solve your issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have the file /tmp/mysql.sock, create a symlink to the actual socket file.  You will have to locate it first, but mine was here:

/etc/mysql/my.cnf

That should fix it, as long as mysql is actually installed and running, check using this:

ps aux | grep mysql

Answer (score -1):

I changed the sockets in /etc/mysql/my.cnf, then it worked fine.